# how to test form authentication having submit function in REST API using Rest Assured

Tags: java, json, jackson, rest-assured, unirest

i am testing REST API which requries form athentication before betting ouput as Json. if i want to get list of students in academic from EndPoint "http://test.api.com/dashboards/all/studentlist/" so when i trigger this endpoint it will redirect to login html page and ask for authentication there need to provide username password and need to submit the form using login button then only output is displayed i am using Rest Assured  using java for testing i have tried below code still no luck getting login html page as ouput

form in Login HTML Page

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" action="/xxx/xxxxx/Redirect">
              <div class="form-element-wrapper">
                <label for="username">myUsername</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-element form-field" id="username" name="j_username" value=""/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-element-wrapper">
                <label for="password">myPassword</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-element form-field" id="password" name="j_password" value=""/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-element-wrapper">
                <input type="checkbox" name="donotcache" value="1"/>
 Don't Remember Login                            </div>
              <div class="form-element-wrapper">
                <input type="checkbox" id="_shib_idp_revokeConsent" name="_shib_idp_revokeConsent" value="true"/>

                Clear prior granting of permission for release of your information to this service.                            </div>
              <div class="form-element-wrapper">
                <button type="submit" class="form-element form-button" name="_eventId_proceed" onclick="this.childNodes[0].nodeValue='Logging in, please wait...'">Login</button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

baseURL is logon page (provided form action attribute value here) and URL2 is acutul api which requries authentication for getting output.

```
given().auth().form("admin", "admin", new FormAuthConfig(BaseURL, "j_username", "j_password")).when().get(URL2).then().statusCode(200).log().all();
```

the output i am getting is a login html page.  how to do login and get the Json response.
how to do these kind of redirect authentications Please help me

thanks in advance

regards,
anji

Anybody please respond ,  help me in this scenarios

Comment: is login api available to you?? as you are trying to verify API you should have login api. if you want to login  you have to call login api.

Comment: no login Api is not there the authenticatoin shoild be done by above said process only

Comment: Hi all can anybody Please help me to resolve this thanks in adavence